# Strange characters which are similar with familiar characters

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, character, special-characters

While looking into some data, I tend to find characters like

```
’‘♯＂“”＆，
```

These are similar with but not exactly the same as,

```
''#"""&,
```

respectively, which are familiar characters which can be found on keyboard.

What are those special characters ’‘♯＂“”＆?

I guess there are much more characters like these. Could you provide me the entire list of such special characters?

Also, how can I easily replace these with more familiar characters? Would python do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look to be unicode characters. Luckily it is easy to replace them.

To replace the small number sign, which is unicode character FEF5, you'd simply do this:

```
str.replace(u"\uFEF5", "#")
```

For a full list of unicode characters: [Unicode page/search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm)

Comment: Thank you! Your link also is great!